# How to remove unwanted subdomain with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

For whatever reason, my client's site is showing up in Google with a competitors phone number in the subdomain.  Not all results, but several results are showing it now.

So what should be www.clientsite.com is coming up with www.800-555-1212www.clientsite.com

How do I set my .htaccess to keep it just as www.clientsite.com?

Comment: ?! That's the best contra-marketing tip ever! Just add your phone number to all competitor DNS aliases... Ah, thanks Chris, made my day...

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.clientsite\.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.clientsite.com/$0 [redirect=permanent,L]
```

Comment: That's not doing it either.  Plus, the site now works without the www.

Comment: You won't get result NOW. Google is caching stuff, so you will have to way a long time before you can see the result in Google. Also - any site SHOULD work without the www.

Comment: I made a little error. The redirect didn't work because there was also www after the phone number. I fixed this by adding an extra ^ in the mask (as shown in the edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this works

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.clientsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.clientsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.clientsite/$0 [redirect=permanent,L]
```